# Convert array of integers in one ascii string using JSONata

Tags: jsonata

Imagine I have following JSON:
{"value2:[72,101,108,108,111,32,87,111,114,108,100]} and I want to have the result "Hello World". How to do this in JSONata?

I did not find any command to convert the decimal value to their corresponding ascii.

Answer (score 0):

```
{ "value2": [72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 87, 111, 114, 108, 100] }
```

To convert the array into the string "Hello World" using JSONata, you can use the following expression:

```
$value2.^$fromMillis()
```

complete JSONata expression applied to the JSON object:

```
{ "expression": "$value2.^$fromMillis()"}
```

Comment: Does not work for me. I tried here: https://try.jsonata.org/